# Subprocess.popen multiple scripts - wait for each script to finish

Tags: python, subprocess, rhino3d

I have a problem executing multiple scripts with subprocess in python and Rhino. I want to import dxf/xyz files, rename layers and split the objects. The 3 scripts work individually but when executed via subprocess, the script for bbox-splitting starts running before renaming the layers has finished, hence isn’t working properly. Any idea how to wait for each script to finish before starting the next one?

```
script_call_dxf = "_-RunPythonScript {} ".format(dxf_script_path)       
script_call_xyz = "_-RunPythonScript {} ".format(xyz_script_path)
script_call_bbox = "_-RunPythonScript {} ".format(bbox_script_path)

call_script = '"{0}" /nosplash /runscript="{1} {2} {3}", "{4}"'.format(rhino_path, script_call_xyz, script_call_dxf, script_call_bbox, rhino_file)

subprocess.run(call_script)
```

Comment: What operating system are you targeting? On anything except Windows, trying to use string concatenation to generate a command is a Very Bad Idea, and one should build an argument vector _as a list_ instead. (Windows has design misfeatures that make the very bad idea mandatory; it's not that it stops being a bad idea, but it's that one can't get away from it: the idea of there being such a thing as a string representation of a command line is baked into how processes start each other).

Comment: Well yes it's Windows. I know it's not elegant, but for the moment this is the only way I can think of, to go all the way withotut having to manually click something. Is there a way to target the running program (Rhino) with a second subprocess.popen instead of starting it new?

Comment: Insofar as Rhino has [several supported APIs](https://developer.rhino3d.com/), it probably makes sense to start there. The way I understand it, the problem is that the scripts you're running don't block until the work they do is complete. Ideally, you could modify the scripts so they _do_ block; or create a single script that's handed off to Rhino at once that's responsible for waiting before each piece. But my expertise is just Python -- I don't know Rhino -- so the Rhino-centric suggestions are necessarily speculative.